# nginx, redirect to remove a part of filename

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx

I've seen a couple similar questions with solutions, but they didn't work for me. Mainly because in all of them the part to be deleted is in the beginning of URL but in my case it's in the middle.
I need to convert URL like http://123.123.123.123:9090/v0/A8B9DEBF512F929144257AEE00262C16/$File/IMG_8819.jpg to http://123.123.123.123:9090/v0/A8B9DEBF512F929144257AEE00262C16/IMG_8819.jpg (without $File/, instead of A8B9DEBF512F929144257AEE00262C16 and IMG_8819.jpg there may be any combination of digits and letters)?

I tried something like this

```
location /v0 {
    rewrite ^(v0/[^/]+)/\$File/(.*)$ $1/$2 last;
}
```

with no avail. But obviously it's regex that's wrong, 'cause at least nginx recognizes that it should do something with /v0/ and I get 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you want to "delete" `/$File`. Do that by capturing everything before and after, then putting it back:

```
location /v0 {
    rewrite ^(.*)/\$File(.*)$ $1$2 last;
}
```